# Rails, Ember, Redis, nginx and docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, docker, ember.js, redis

Colleagues, I have a front-end application based on Ember and Rails (running on nginx) which also uses redis as a cache.

I want to dockerize this application, but not sure about best practices. Would it be best to create one container with a dockerfile that pulls in all these pieces, or should each component be in its own container?

For bonus points: I have to retrieve the code from private bitbucket repos and.. how are we meant to store our secrets and other config files when using containers?

Comment: Commenting as a reminder to myself to answer this, cause I use docker pretty heavily. On a plane now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'll try my best from a phone,

Secrets are to be kept in environment variables, so you may need to update your application code to work with those.

As for dockerizing, I typically do backend (rails in this case) in one (or more) container(s)  and nginx in a single container bundled with a single page app (ember in this case)

So, you should have two dockerfiles total.

Here are some resources that hopefully provide enough to get started:

Dotnet + react: https://github.com/sillsdev/appbuilder-portal/
Modern bleeding edge ember: https://gitlab.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberclear/
Old ember: https://gitlab.com/precognition-llc/aeonvera-ui
Rails: https://gitlab.com/precognition-llc/aeonvera

For the nginx, that first link shows a dotnet core and react app with nginx and has the deployment strategy I've described. For nginx, you'll start with a node container, or the ember-cli image from danlynn (who still hasn't responded to me about getting those on the official ember docketed), and use multistage builds to eventually copy your dist folder to a directory in the nginx container in the last stage.

Hope this helps. I can clarify more if needed.

Comment: This is certainly helpful. I've understood we can use docker secrets https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ but only on docker swarm? Would it be prudent to link to a directory on the host where secret files would be stored?

Comment: I've also got Redis in the mix, would that go on its own container? Both rails and another node process need to communicate with Redis.

Comment: Yeah, Redis would be its own container. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with docker swarm, only used rancher and kubernetes and heroku.

Comment: But, basically, anything secret shouldn't exist in a file :)

Comment: Though, if it's anything like kubernetes, using the built-in secrets for the platform should be sufficient

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to have a 'secret' image for secrets? That's probably an antipattern. By the way, awesome app `emberclear` so cool